# How to read a C struct (or Numpy record array) into a Polars Dataframe?

Tags: numpy, struct, python-polars

I have a binary file containing records from a C struct. I would like to read that file into a Polars Dataframe.

I can accomplish that as below, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct path?

My current solution involves:

- Reading the file into a Numpy record array (see below) using using `np.fromfile()`
- Converting that into a Pandas DataFrame
- Converting that to a Polars DataFrame

```py
# Data read in from file using np.fromfile()
data = np.array([(1, 2002, 2, 13, 0.3),
                 (2, 2005, 1, -10, 1.5),
                 (3, 2004, 2, 54, -0.12)],
    dtype=[("id", "<i4"),("yr", "<u2"),("sex", "<u2"),("val1", "<i2"),("val2", "<f4")]
)
df = pl.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data))
df
```

```
 id   yr    sex val1    val2
i32  u16    u16  i16     f32
  1 2002      2   13     0.3
  2 2005      1  -10     1.5
  3 2004      2   54   -0.12
```

I've tried reading `data` directly into Polars from numpy using `pl.DataFrame(data)` or `pl.from_records(data)`, but in both cases I get a single column dataframe of type "object", which I can't work out how to separate into separate columns or convert to a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```python
data = np.array([(1, 2002, 2, 13, 0.3),
                (2, 2005, 1, -10, 1.5),
                (3, 2004, 2, 54, -0.12)],
    dtype=[("id", "<i4"),("yr", "<u2"),("sex", "<u2"),("val1", "<i2"),("val2", "<f4")]
)

pl.DataFrame(
    {
        field_name: data[field_name]
        for field_name in data.dtype.fields
    }
)
```

```
┌─────┬──────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ yr   ┆ sex ┆ val1 ┆ val2  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i32 ┆ u16  ┆ u16 ┆ i16  ┆ f32   │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2002 ┆ 2   ┆ 13   ┆ 0.3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2005 ┆ 1   ┆ -10  ┆ 1.5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2004 ┆ 2   ┆ 54   ┆ -0.12 │
└─────┴──────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

To convert back to a numpy struct array, assign a numpy array per field:

```python
# Create numpy struct array of the correct size.
numpy_struct_array = np.empty(df.height, data.dtype)

# Fill in the correct values.
for field, col in zip(data.dtype.fields, df.columns):
    numpy_struct_array[field] = df.get_column(col).to_numpy()

numpy_struct_array
```

```
array([(1, 2002, 2,  13,  0.3 ), (2, 2005, 1, -10,  1.5 ),
       (3, 2004, 2,  54, -0.12)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('yr', '<u2'), ('sex', '<u2'), ('val1', '<i2'), ('val2', '<f4')])
```

Comment: Thanks @ghuls! Going back the other way, can we do better than this: `np.array([tuple(rec) for rec in zip(*[df.get_column(col).to_numpy() for col in df.columns])], dtype=data.dtype)` where `df` is your Polars Dataframe above?

Comment: This should be more performant (assigning a numpy array per field):

``` lang-python
# Create numpy struct array of the correct size.
numpy_struct_array = np.empty(df.height, data.dtype)

# Fill in the correct values.
for field, col in zip(data.dtype.fields, df.columns):
    numpy_struct_array[field] = df.get_column(col).to_numpy()

numpy_struct_array
```

```
array([(1, 2002, 2,  13,  0.3 ), (2, 2005, 1, -10,  1.5 ),
       (3, 2004, 2,  54, -0.12)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('yr', '<u2'), ('sex', '<u2'), ('val1', '<i2'), ('val2', '<f4')])
```

Comment: Thanks again @ghuls. Yes that is much more performant!! Both methods require the numpy dtype though.
I can generate one using `dtype = df.head().to_pandas().to_records(index=False).dtype`
Do you know if there is any easy method to generate a numpy.dtype directly from Polars?

Comment: This seems to do the trick! `dtype = np.dtype([(col, df.head().get_column(col).to_numpy().dtype) for col in df.columns])`